# Howto merge a svn repository with a git cloned repository (imported from SVN via github)

Tags: svn, git, clone, mirroring

In the past I've have used GitHub's import functionality to import a SVN repository.
The repository is now the same as a bare git without any connection to SVN history. The commits don't include `svn-id` information.

Some time has passed and commits were added to the SVN repository but as expected the git repository remained the same.

So now I would like to 'update' the git repository with the commits that were added to the original SVN. I've tried `git-svn` but I couldn't make git recognize the common history between the cloned svn and the cloned git.

I've considered using `format-patch` and I believe this action should solve the problem however I was looking for a more automated way of doing it.

The only restriction is that the git history should be maintained (no `rebase`'ing) and that commits are as faithful to the SVN repository as possible (no `svn-id` added to the commit message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, getting the commits to "merge" properly isn't really going to work here.  You will have to use `format-patch`.  Here is how I would do it:

```
$ git svn clone --no-metadata svn://.../ new-svn-repo
$ cd new-svn-repo
$ git log
```

(You may wish to add the `-A` option to `git svn clone` to rewrite the SVN authorship information from a `user@uuid` format into proper `Joe User <user@example.com>` authorship information.  See `man git-svn` for information.)

Look through the log and find the commit that corresponds to the latest commit in the github repository.  If that is commit `abcdef` then:

```
$ git format-patch -k abcdef
```

You will now have a whole slew of `*.patch` files that correspond to the new commits you want to port over.  So...

```
$ cp *.patch /github/repository/location
$ cd /github/repository/location
$ git am -k --keep-cr *.patch
```

Tada!  Now just push master to Github.

(If your Git is not new enough it may complain about the `--keep-cr` argument to `git am`.  If your source files do not contain CRs then just remove `--keep-cr`.  But if they do, you may need to upgrade your Git since `git mailsplit`, called by `git am`, will strip all of the CRs in the patch files out when processing them.  This may cause patches to fail to apply.)

Comment: The only problem I found with this is that git-am adds my user as "commiter". Do you have any idea how to prevent this? I've checked git-am documentation but couldn't find anything explicit.

Comment: Well, it should, shouldn't it?  You were the one to commit to the Git repository.  If you don't like that, you can use `git-filter-branch` to rewrite the history that you imported.